# Electric field inside conductor with potential difference across the conductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-current

Suppose we have a conductor of length $L$ and uniform cross-sectional area $A$. Let us apply a potential difference $V$ between the ends of the conductor. Then the electric field inside the conductor is

Comment: "inside the conductor is"? What are you hoping for?

Comment: What is the electric field inside the conductor in that case

Comment: Hint: if the conductor has a uniform conductivity, then you can use the microscopic form of Ohm's Law that links the current density and the electric field.

Answer (score 0):

The units should give you a hint. The electric field has units of volts per meter. You have a quantity in volts and a quantity in units of meters.